# Questions about setting alarm days in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an alarm function similar to the iPhone alarm app.

When setting the alarm day, I am writing code to check the day of the week.

```
class DaySelectCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkView: Checkbox!
}
```

```
import UIKit

class DaySelectViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let days = ["일요일마다","월요일마다","화요일마다","수요일마다","목요일마다","금요일마다","토요일마다"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension DaySelectViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DaySelectCell") as! DaySelectCell

        cell.dayLbl.text = days[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DaySelectCell") as! DaySelectCell
    }
}
```

The part I want to ask is `didSelectRowAt`
I want to make a `checkView.isSelectd` of that cell to be `true` when I click on a certain day cell.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your original question: Check out [Calendar's standaloneWeekdaySymbols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293469-standaloneweekdaysymbols) property. Then you don't have to manage the list of week days in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage datasource to hold the selected value, So you can pretend which index is selected.

```
var selectedDays: [Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   cell.accessoryType = selectedDays.contains(indexPath.row) ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

Now in `didSelectRowAt` method write this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let index = selectedDays.firstIndex(where: { $0 == indexPath.row }) {
        selectedDays.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        selectedDays.append(indexPath.row)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```